# Displaying MYSQL row number or position with pagination start and limit

Tags: mysql, pagination, numbers, row, limit

i need a query that can display row number sequence when we have pagination. I have a problem the row number always the same when we click at next page or previous page. Please help! see hyperlink below.

```
$result=mysql_query("select @rownum:=@rownum+1 rownumber, t.* from tablekad t, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r order by tarikh asc LIMIT $start, $limit");
```

[Page 1 <-- here the problem](http://www.kaer-media.org/problem/pagination1.jpg)

[Page 2 <---- here the link for page 2 the problem](http://www.kaer-media.org/problem/pagination2.jpg)

Can with a single query we can display correctly the row number when we click the next page or previous ? Any solution for this? Please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you want with a subquery:

```
select t.*
from (select @rownum:=@rownum+1 rownumber, t.*
      from tablekad t cross join
           (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
      order by tarikh asc
     ) t
LIMIT $start, $limit;
```

Technically, you should probably repeat the `order by` on the outer query.  In practice, this is probably not necessary.